# Why is the "repo" package unavailable in Ubuntu 20.04? How can I install it?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, repository

I tried to install `repo` , but `apt` said that package is not available. I refreshed package lists cache by `apt update` , but the same message.

So, I opened my browser and searched Ubuntu repositories for "repo" by going to the URL https://packages.ubuntu.com/repo. I saw that a `repo` package is available for xenial, bionic, eoan and even the upcoming groovy release. But it is not available for my Ubuntu, 20.04 Focal Fossa.

Why isn't it available? How can I install it?

Comment: It isn't available in Ubuntu 20.04 because it's developers were slow to transition from Python2 (which will reach EOL in late 2020) to Python3.

Comment: just want to leave a note that repo is back in Ubuntu 21 (hirsute) package repository. version 2.12 / 4 mths old at the moment of writing, but still not bad

Comment: Thanks @maoizm, but I switched to Guix, a free (as in freedom) rolling release distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't want to add eoan to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file permanently so I downloaded the packages manually:

- `python-kerberos` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python-kerberos
- `repo` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/repo

I then installed them using `sudo dpkg -i <filename>`, `python-kerberos` first.

Comment: Doest work! dpkg-deb: error: 'python-kerberos' is not a Debian format archive

Comment: This solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350447/2379079

Comment: Both links in this answer are now dead.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this issue as well and I solved it by manually installing `repo`
from the [repo installation page](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/refs/heads/master/README.md):

Taken from the install instructions:

```
mkdir -p ~/.bin
PATH="${HOME}/.bin:${PATH}"
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/.bin/repo
chmod a+rx ~/.bin/repo
```

Comment: Don't forget to add ~/.bin/ to your path.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to install `repo` by downloading and installing `repo` and it dependency `python-kerberos` from eoan repositories from https://packages.ubuntu.com. To install, type these commands and hit enter:

```bsh
apt update
apt install gnupg python
```

This to ensure that all dependencies are installed. Now download `repo` and it's dependency `python-kerberos` as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually installing `repo` from the
[install manually repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/refs/heads/master/README.md)

and [resolve error Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71538353/10941856)

**This answer for android build system error**
For Python 3

If you get a "/usr/bin/env 'python' no such file or directory" error message, use one of the following solutions:
If your Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is a newly installed (vs. upgraded) Linux version:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

f using Git version 2.19 or greater, you can specify --partial-clone when performing repo init. This makes use of Git's partial clone capability to only download Git objects when needed, instead of downloading everything. Because using partial clones means that many operations must communicate with the server, use the following if you're a developer and you're using a network with low latency:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
```

you can see document in
[Downloading the Source](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/refs/heads/master/README.md)

Comment: Hello. Well this may solve the problem today what about in the future when the links may not work? If there is important info in the links it needs to be in the body of the question.